# Person edited question to get it closed after all answers were 'wrong'

Tags: discussion, downvotes

A person edited [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019874/css-when-people-wrong-they-cant-admit-it) together with its title, presumably because said person is upset because someone "couldn't admit that he or she was wrong". The person has been given the code to fix the issue which he didn't address properly in the first place.

And when he finally found the answer he answered his own question with:

> You all wrong, the problem was that I was missing doctype, for example
>
> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> ```
>
> so my code was working right

and then decided to go on a mass-down-vote spree and change the title of the question and its content. Others are now unable to use this question and learn from their mistakes...

**Edit:** A mod just changed the content back, thank you.

Comment: "mass-down-vote spree"

Comment: Ha ha, you're all wrong! The code wasn't working because my monitor was off! -1 all around.

Comment: "when people wrong they can't admit it" <- only ever spoken by people refusing to admit that they were wrong.

Comment: eh, it's hard to judge in this case. I want to say it's an unclear question because the code doesn't recreate the problem, but... it kinda does recreate it, if and only if you leave off the doctype.

Comment: Just goes to show how important an MCVE is.  Had the OP did that it would have saved everybody the wasted effort.

Comment: @NathanOliver It also goes to show that you should be careful when trying to answer a question without an MCVE; doing so is bringing problems like this onto yourself.

Comment: @resueman: Does that make you one of those people?

Comment: @BoltClock Of course not. That would require me being wrong, which I refuse to admit.

Comment: Weird. There is not one but **two** downvotes on almost every answer. Seems someone strongly agreed with the OP.

Comment: @RadLexus well... the answers are wrong after all. regardless of how rude the OP was.

Comment: *it kinda does recreate it, if and only if you leave off the doctype.* @KevinB Yes, but the question didn't (and still doesn't) contain that information. It may have enough code to reproduce the problem, but it doesn't have enough *info* to recreate the problem. It's like leaving out the fact that an error only happens on mobile browsers or that you have to tab over to a button and hit enter instead of clicking on it.

Comment: You have to love it when somebody asks a question, gets an answer (granted not very good answers), and then gets upset because they got an answer to the question they asked instead of the one they didn't ask and didn't even hint at.

Comment: Technically the OP's (poorly written) answer is  the correct answer and he has the right to answer his own question in that case (no other answers actually answered it), but he doesn't have the write to make the answer an attack on the other posters.  The edited answer is still not very good.  It should at least address why leaving off the doctype can cause problems like that (make it informative for everybody instead of just, "I changed this line, now it works").

Comment: @Matthew Downvoting *incorrect answers* and posting a comment to say that they're not correct is not an "attack" on other answers.  It's exactly the right action when someone posts an incorrect answer to the question, which they shouldn't have done, given that the question was too unclear to answer in the first place.

Comment: Can someone with 10k+ please post a screenshot of the deleted question and its answers?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Looks like the answers were wrong, because they tried to answer an unclear question.  The lesson here is to avoid attempting to answer unclear questions, rather than to answer unclear questions and then get mad at the author for clarifying the problem to be different than what you assumed it was asking.  It's *correct* for someone guessing at what an unclear question is asking to get downvotes, especially if it's clear that *they guessed wrong*.  If that's not a consequence that you're prepared for, then *don't answer unclear questions*.

Of course, the OP's vandalism of the question is inappropriate, and has been correctly rolled back.  If they had edited the question to clarify their problem better, in such a way that it made it obvious that the answers guessing at the problem were wrong, that would be fine, but just editing the whole thing to lorem ipsum is clear vandalism.

Comment: I think this can be boiled down to: Sometimes when you take a stab in the dark you wind up stabbing yourself.

Comment: @NathanOliver  Or a kitten.

Comment: This answer should be mandatory reading.  "It's correct for someone guessing at what an unclear question is asking to get downvotes, especially if it's clear that they guessed wrong. "

Comment: A lot of the OPs behavior here is wrong.  A moderator needs to take a good look at the comments in that question - they are pretty hostile and rude (from both sides, but mostly the OPs).  I'd flag that for attention, but have had similar flags declined and don't want any more declined flags.  Using an answer as an attack on the other posters is obviously very wrong as well.

Comment: @Matthew Saying that an incorrect answer is incorrect is neither hostile nor rude.  It's exactly the correct action to be taking.  Their answer isn't inappropriate in any way.   The only problem that I see here is the people attacking him for correctly informing others that they posted incorrect answers.  Downvoting and deleting the correct answer, and upvoting an incorrect answer, just because the OP posted an unclear question (that he later clarified) is extremely inappropriate of the community, not the OP.

Comment: @Servy I don't mean the answer as it stands now (actually it has since been deleted).  The original version is a bit hostile.  The edited version was just fine (although it could be stand to be expanded some to be a better answer).  I didn't say that he was wrong to inform other posters that their answer was wrong, or even to downvote, either.  I just felt that his tone while doing so was a bit too strong.  I also don't see where he clarified the question.  The only clarification comes in comments on one of the answers.

Comment: @Matthew I specifically noted that the answer was deleted. That deletion was *extremely* inappropriate, considering it's the only correct answer to the question.  And again, I don't consider the answer inappropriate at all.  It's not a quality answer, but it's not an *inappropriate* one.  The actions of the other people interacting with the question seem largely far more inappropriate to me than the OP's actions.

Comment: @Servy I never did vote down the answer for exactly the reason that you say - it was correct.  I agree that it shouldn't have been deleted, and mass downvoted.  Nor did I vote up any of the others, because they were incorrect.  What is inappropriate is starting the answer with **"You all wrong"**  How does that improve the answer?  The later edit to remove that makes it a much better answer.

Comment: @Matthew It's not a part of the answer to the question, so it's okay to remove it, but it's certainly not inappropriate behavior, just noise.  If he had signed his name at the end it would also merit removal for the same reason.